# Setting MySql Session Variables

Tags: mysql, jdbc

We noticed that some of the queries we were running in our spring/java environment were coming back with truncated columns. The problem was group_concat_max_len was set too small.
I tried modifying our database definition .sql file to include SET SESSION:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS acmedb;
CREATE DATABASE acmedb;

USE acmedb;

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 6999;

CREATE TABLE...
```

However this is not going into effect after a db reload. I have to do a jdbctemplate execute() statement with this code for it to propogate. While that fixes the problem I was wondering if anyone can tell me why executing it via sql script does not do anything.

**EDIT**
In another attempt to fix the problem I tried dropping the following line in our Dao init() method:

```
this.jdbcTemplateObject.execute("SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 6999 ");
```

This fixes the problem... sometimes. I think eventually the session expires and this change is lost. What are the rules on mysql set session in terms of longevity of the call? I could put this statement before every query is executed but that seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead.